# Extract substring with regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

How to extract a substring after keyword `am`, `is` or `are` from a string but not include `am`, `is` or `are`?

```
string = 'I am John'
```

I used:

```
re.findall('(?<=(am|is|are)).*', string)
```

An error occurs

```
re.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern
```

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import re

s = 'I am John'

g = re.findall(r'(?:am|is|are)\s+(.*)', s)
print(g)
```

Prints:

```
['John']
```

Answer (score 3):

In cases like this I like to use `finditer` because the match objects it returns are easier to manipulate than the strings returned by `findall`. You can continue to match am/is/are, but also match the rest of the string with a second subgroup, and then extract only that group from the results.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'I am John'
>>> [m.group(2) for m in re.finditer("(am|is|are)(.*)", string)]
[' John']
```

---

Based on the structure of your pattern, I'm guessing you only want at most one match out of the string. Consider using `re.search` instead of either findall or finditer.

```
>>> re.search("(am|is|are)(.*)", string).group(2)
' John'
```

If you're thinking "actually I want to match every instance of a word following am/is/are, not just the first one", that's a problem, because your `.*` component will match the entire rest of the string after the first am/is/are. E.g. for the string `"I am John and he is Steve"`, it will match `' John and he is Steve'`. If you want John and Steve separately, perhaps you could limit the character class that you want to match. `\w` seems sensible:

```
>>> string = "I am John and he is Steve"
>>> [m.group(2) for m in re.finditer(r"(am|is|are) (\w*)", string)]
['John', 'Steve']
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is using partition function. there is an example

```
string = 'I am John'
words = ['am','is','are']

for word in words :
    before,word,after = string.partition(word)
    print (after)
```

OUTPUT :

```
 John
```